# Snapshots of data in iCloud enabled Core Data app?

Tags: core-data, icloud, snapshot

My app syncs and backups its data via iCloud (I'm using [iCloudCoreDataStack](https://github.com/mluisbrown/iCloudCoreDataStack) for this purpose). As my app handles important data created by the user, I want to offer an additional safety net by the ability to create snapshots from time to time which can be restored later.

I'm not talking about undoing one or two single changes, but about real snapshots, timestamped and stored in a save manner.

As I am leveraging the iCloud sync, I cannot simply exchange the sqlite store used in the app. I think I have to delete every object in the current context, create the objects restored from the snapshot and save the context. Then, the device will push the changes to iCloud too.

I'm thinking of the following scenario:

1. The app works normal without the option to create snapshots (it's just an optional safety feature for the user).
2. If the user opts in to create snapshots from time to time, he's asked to enter his Dropbox login credentials (already implemented).
3. From time to time, my app then creates a background thread in which a second store and a second MOC (and a second PSC?) will be set up. Every object together with its relationships gets copied into this 2nd MOC. The 2nd MOC gets saved, the persistent store will be copied to Dropbox and the thread will end.
4. If the user wants to restore a snapshot and discard every change made after the creation of the snapshot, my app will rebuild the data by reversely doing what's described in point 3.

Any thoughts of that? Is this save to do, are there any caveats to think of (esp. together with iCloud)? Has anyone done this yet in a similar way?

---

**Edit:**

I was successful in creating a copy of the store with the steps described above. Recreation of the store seemed also to work in some first tries. But, I still have worries about my way of loading the store file (pulling the old file away and then replacing it with my saved one).

However, I've come across Apples "*Save as...*" or "*Relocate*" method

```
NSDictionary *options = @{
    NSPersistentStoreRemoveUbiquitousMetadataOption: @YES
};
NSPersistentStore *copy = [psc migratePersistentStore:currentiCloudStore
                                                toURL:url
                                              options:options
                                             withType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                                error:&error];
```

which will remove all iCloud associated metadata, and also removes the current store from the coordinator (I don't want that) and adds the newly created store to the PSC (I don't want that either).

What is the better way to go? My current approach or Apples's built in "*Save as... / Relocate*"? My focus lies on loading the snapshots back in later, no matter if iCloud was/is enabled or not.

Answer (score 1):

Your basic approach looks good to me. I am also using the iCloudCoreDataStack which I think is a robust solution.

I don't understand why you are iterating through all objects and recreate them if you want to save a new store. Simply save all, lock the store, make a local copy, unlock the store (the user can continue working now), and copy the store up to DropBox. When restoring, overwrite the existing store with the downloaded one (if on the same device and sandbox still exists, no need to download). At this point you would likely have to reset the iCloud store as well.

That being said, if you are already iterating through the object graph, you might use that to do something extra that could turn out to be useful. You could convert the entire object graph into JSON and store that as a text file (if there are no transformable or binary attributes). Your data is now human readable and usable in many more ways and by many more platforms.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to do so. Any thoughts on my edit regarding Apple's build in "Relocate" method?

Answer (score 1):

I've also been looking for a solution to allow my users to perform a backup snapshot. I couldn't use migratePersistentStore because it removed my active store in the process. I then wondered if I could add the store to a DIFFERENT PSC and then migrate it, thereby leaving the original PSC untouched. This code for backing up appears to work without interrupting my live stack. I'm slightly unsure about adding a store to 2 PSCs though.

```
- (void)backupStore {//saves the store to backup.sqlite

    NSFileManager *fm = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
    NSError *localError = nil;
    _ubiquityURL = [fm URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
    NSURL *backupStoreURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"backupStore.sqlite"]];
    NSURL *iCloudStoreURL = [self iCloudStoreURL];
    NSMutableDictionary *options = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],     NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                                [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption,
                                nil];
   [options setObject:@"Logbook" forKey:NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey];
 //Add the store to tempPSC
   NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *tempPSC = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil]];
    NSPersistentStore *store = [tempPSC addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:iCloudStoreURL options:options error:&localError];
   //migrate the store to local database
    options = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],   NSPersistentStoreRemoveUbiquitousMetadataOption,nil];
    if ([tempPSC migratePersistentStore:store toURL:backupStoreURL options:options withType:NSSQLiteStoreType error:&localError]) {
        NSLog(@"migratePersistentStore did it!!");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"migratePersistentStore failed!!...%@",localError);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for you approach. I've requested a TSI at Apple and let you know what they say when I get a reply from them.

Comment: Did the TSI response say it was okay to include this in a shipping app?

Answer (score 1):

In creating the backup store, be aware that there are reports that migratePersistentStore will nuke all many-to-many relationships without any error or indication that it is doing so. I have a backup function in my app (with a similar one for sharing over Bonjour) using migratePersistentStore and started getting some user reports of missing data. While the above solutions will work, you may be silently losing data. Or, if you don't have any many-to-many relationships in your scheme, you'll hopefully be fine. Not a great feeling for a "backup" function, right?

I was struggling with this for days until I found Ivan Pavlov's post at https://devforums.apple.com/message/1055235#1055235 where he filed radar 18480943 on this.

To sum up, I wouldn't use migratePersistentStore if your schema has many-to-many relationships, unless you also go back and manually recreate all the links in those relationships after the migration.

Answer (score 0):

I current allow the user to use a File Save As menu option to create a backup copy of any Core Data files on OS X and this uses the migratePersistentStore API to create the new copy without iCloud options.  Of course this is not necessary if the file is not already stored in iCloud, the user could just copy the file using file manager. On iOS devices you would use the same approach, except you need to write your own file manager to copy any files so it's probably easier to just use the migratePersistentStore API to create the new file.  In order to restore a file you need to migrate it to iCloud, you can't just copy it back.  Take a look at this link where I have posted some explanations and sample code and some videos showing how files get moved to and from iCloud when the use changes their iCloud preference settings.  This app is a document based app so allows the creation of multiple documents, it would be trivial to just add a popup menu on the FileListViewController for making a backup file to the location of your choice.

http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/uimanageddocument-icloud-integration/